# is it possible to process the SOAP xml request using java code and get the response?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have `SOAP` request `XML` but i don't have `URL`.

so is it possible to process the request using java code and get the response?

i have searched on this but i got only by url we can do. I am new to SOAP.

Comment: You mean to say you have the WSDL file?

Comment: yes, i have wsdl file xml but don't have wsdl url

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/generating-client-java-code) one. If you are using Eclipse or IntelliJ, there are specific guidelines to do the same in those too.

Comment: i checked this. but it is using SOAP ui. but i want to write the code for request xml

Comment: this is generating the Java code only.

Comment: i don't have wsdl url but i have request xml file only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166511/discussion-between-sandeep-randhawa-and-sangram-badi).